# Redirect back after back press on settings activity

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application, I start an intent for the settings, but when the user presses the back button on the settings activity, the user gets back to the home screen. Instead, I want him to get back to the activity that started the settings intent.

Here is my code for starting the settings intent:

```
 Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but what happens if you use `startActivityForResult` instead (without actually expecting a result)?

Comment: pass intent like this Intent inte=new Intent(yourActivity.this,SettingActivity.class);startActivity(inte);Override onBackPressed() in settings activity and call finish() in back pressed

Comment: but settings activity is android's default settings activity. Cannot override it